# My code does not work, It won't input the values from $_SESSION to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I need help inputting the values from $_SESSION to the database, i get no errors but nothing is added to the database table. please help

Here are my codes.

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","12148qx3er");
$db = @mysql_select_db("buybranded");
include("includes/functions.php");
mysql_set_charset("UTF8");

if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='update'){

    $first_name=$_SESSION['first_name'];
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
    $home_address=$_SESSION['home_address'];
    $mobile_number=$_SESSION['mobile_number'];
    $result=mysql_query("insert into customers(name,email,address,phone) values('','$first_name','$email','$home_address','$mobile_number')");

    $customerid=mysql_insert_id();
    $date=date('Y-m-d');
    $result=mysql_query("insert into orders values('','$date','$customerid')");

    $orderid=mysql_insert_id();
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $price=get_price($pid);
        mysql_query("insert into order_detail values ($orderid,$pid,$q,$price)");
    }
    die('Thank You! your order has been placed!');
}
?>
```

Here is the checklogin.php where i place the values of $_SESSION.

```
<?php


$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="12148qx3er"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="buybranded"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$email = stripslashes($email);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

session_start();
$_SESSION["email"] = $email;
$_SESSION["password"] = $password;
$_SESSION["first_name"] = $first_name;
$_SESSION["middle_name"] = $middle_name;
$_SESSION["last_name"] = $last_name;
$_SESSION["gender"] = $gender;
$_SESSION["birth_date"] = $birth_date;
$_SESSION["home_address"] = $home_address;
$_SESSION["mobile_number"] = $mobile_number;
$_SESSION["home_phone"] = $home_phone;
$_SESSION["postal_code"] = $postal_code;
$_SESSION["city"] = $city;
$_SESSION["province"] = $province;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //remove this line ******header("location:customer_home.php");
    if($row['type'] == 'admin'){
        header("location: admin.php");
    } else if($row['type'] == 'customer'){
        header("location: customer_home.php");
    }
}
}

else {

header('refresh: 0.1; url=sign-in.php');
$message = "Invalid Email or Password, Redirecting..";
die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>"); // To prevent evil     people manipulating the page, kill the script using die.

}

?>
```

Comment: Where do you define the session variables? Cause now you post items from out of the session where we dont know where they are defined. Did you echo them out? Did you echo out your query?

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injection. Also, the mysql library is deprecated and will be removed. You should use PDO or MySQLi and use prepared statements.

Comment: P.S. You should change your database password, since you just posted it on SO...

Comment: "I get no errors" - `@` hides errors from that line, how do you know you are connected to the database?

Comment: Why do you put so much in your session, the user id should be sufficient? Also your login code is using variables that were never intialized and storing them in your session (variables should be gotten from the mysql request but are not). This is also bad database design, try learning about foreign keys. This is bad php code, try using mysqli or pdo.

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated and should not be used anymore, it will break in coming PHP versions and your code will be useless. use mysqli

Answer (score 0):

On what looks like line 14 (this one:)

> $result=mysql_query("insert into customers(name,email,address,phone)
>   values('','$first_name','$email','$home_address','$mobile_number')");

you have 5 values listed when you are only inserting into 4 columns. Removing the empty string for the first value should help match it up. perhaps a query error and not a session issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, wrap `'` in `$price` and `$q` column values

```
"insert into order_detail values ($orderid,$pid,'$q','$price')"
```

instead of

```
"insert into order_detail values ($orderid,$pid,$q,$price)"
```

Also, column count mismatched

```
$result=mysql_query("insert into customers(name,email,address,phone) values('$first_name','$email','$home_address','$mobile_number')");
```

instead of

```
$result=mysql_query("insert into customers(name,email,address,phone) values('','$first_name','$email','$home_address','$mobile_number')");
```